# How to use DATE_SUB and hours interval in mysql using in vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

SELECT DATE_SUB('2014-01-01 01:00:00', INTERVAL 3 HOUR) ;

I want to use this concept to vb.net
-I have a textbox which store the datetime format

Example no1, I have 2014-01-01 08:00:00 in my textbox and I want to minus 3 hours

Expected Output should be 2014-01-01 05:00:00

Example no2, I have 2014-01-01 01:00:00 in my textbox and I want to minus 3 hours

Expected Output should be 2014-12-31 22:00:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about:

```
DateTime.Parse( '2014-01-01 01:00:00' ).AddHours( -3 );
```